# Detect a keep-alive signal

Tags: comparator, signal-processing, security

**Reason/Background**
I have a raspberry pi (garage) that's doing some security-related monitoring, and generates a "keep-alive" signal. I would like to have an alarm go off in a separate place (attic) when either the signal stops, or someone tampers with it (cutting the wire or just applying 5v or Gnd to it). This signal consists of a pulse of 5v/150ms each second.

**Question**
Now I was wondering about how to create a circuit that could detect a change in voltage/frequency/duty-cycle. I think what I made below does the trick, in theory.
I do have several concerns about this:

1. does this do what I assume it does?
2. is R1 well-chosen?
3. is R2 even necessary?
4. are R11 and R23 the right values? (I don't mean the setting, but their value of 5kOhm)
5. is LM741 the right choice?
6. is 50uF for the capacitor a realistic value? Is the RC circuit and its charge resistor well-chosen for that matter?
7. is it reliable:

   - interference, should I even worry about it?
   - can it handle temperatures between -30°C and +50°C?
   - age, will this run for 10 years?
   - tolerances in values, what should I pay attention to?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgtJZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are three time-triggered switches on the left, to test each condition. They're programmed to do the following:

- do nothing for 7 seconds
- switch to 5v for 3 seconds
- switch to the keep-alive signal again for 4 seconds
- switch to Gnd

This is what the time-domain plot (don't know if this is the correct term) looks like:
[image: Circuit_plot]
**Purpose**
The purpose of this is two-fold: I really want to make this and use it, and I want to learn from any mistakes I have made. So if you would be kind enough to explain to me why something I did was wrong, or give me resources to learn the answer myself, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think the big mistake here is overcomplicating the problem. Why don't you add signal-conditioning to the 5v input to prevent over-voltage (like a series resistor and a couple of clamping diodes) then do the detection digitally?

Comment: Props for the circuit though. That's pretty impressive. IMO digital detection cuts out a lot of weird edge cases that you just won't have to think about.

Comment: Digital detection would be more ideal indeed, but in my mind that would involve using a µC, something I'd like to avoid due to the lack of necessary tools (and experience). Am I wrong to assume digital detection requires a µC?

Comment: You're already using an RPi... what's wrong with using that?

Comment: The point is that the RPI is generating this signal, and that I want to have an alarm go off when someone tampers with it.. Programming an RPI to do something is effortless compared to doing the same for a µC.

Comment: Ah. In that case I might still go with using a second RPi and connecting them with Ethernet. It's much more flexible that way.

Comment: More flexible, yes. Also: a fairly expensive solution for what it needs to do.. not to mention overkill.

Comment: At 35 bucks, it's the age-old question: what's your time worth?

Comment: In Belgium (which is where I live) an RPI costs about 50€ (which is around 68$). At the moment I have a fair amount of free time, that I want to use for learning electronics by making/designing stuff that both works and is useful.
Also, the power requirements for a RPI setup are considerably larger than an analog one (it might need to run off a battery, if someone cuts the power).

Comment: Ah well I see your point. Thanks for being a sport.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.does this do what I assume it does?

I do believe it does. Subject to a few tweaks, of course.

> 2.is R1 well-chosen?
>   3.is R2 even necessary?

Yes to both, but I would do this a little differently. My concern is that your charge current to the timing cap depends on the amplitude of the pi pulse. Although this is probably consistent, my ingrained paranoia suggest that you do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXhcaP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

ETA: Carp! R6 is your 40 k. Sorry. Stick with 40k.

This way, the charge current is independent of the input pulse amplitude as long as it is more than ~1 volt.

> 4.are R11 and R23 the right values? (I don't mean the setting, but their value of 5kOhm)

Yup

> 5.is LM741 the right choice?

Nope, on 2 counts. First, a 741 is not rated for use as a single 5 volt amplifier. Second, its output swing is not what you want. I'd suggest LM311s.

And while we're on this section, I'd advise each comparator use this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZmrXJ.png)</sup>

ETA: Sorry, R1 should be 1k - 10k.

This will provide clean switching when a level is reached. And do not forget decoupling caps if you value your sanity.

> 6.is 50uF for the capacitor a realistic value? Is the RC circuit and its charge resistor well-chosen for that matter?

Yes to both.

> 7.is it reliable: •interference, should I even worry about it?

Yes, and good on yer for thinking about it now. You can probably get away with using twisted pair to connect the pi to your circuit.

> •can it handle temperatures between -30°C and +50°C?

*Excellent* question. Yes it can, but you'll need milspec (or at least industrial) parts, particularly for the comparators. Commercial temp ranges are usually only 0 to 70 C. But check all the part ratings when you buy them.

> •age, will this run for 10 years?

I don't see why not, as long as you do things like cleaning all the solder flux from your pc board. The weakest link is probably your 50 uF cap, followed by your 5 volt supply, but there's not much you can do about that.

> •tolerances in values, what should I pay attention to?

1 % is normal in resistors these days, and caps will run about 10% to 20%, but you'll adjust for that in setting your pots. Not a major concern.